# Can you tell me know how my images look in Safari

Tags: image, safari, retina-display, image-scaling, retina

I'm currently trying to test out this new css rule, which fixes the blurry retina image downscaling in Chrome.

I described the problem in detail here: [Blurry downscaled images in the Chrome 84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502778/blurry-downscaled-images-in-the-chrome-84)

The rule I applied to my **img** tags is this: **image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast**

While it fixes the blurry problem in Chrome, I heard that it can mess up how images look in Safari. I'd really appreciate if someone who uses Safari on a Retina display (laptop) would check if images on [this site](https://www.pianodreamers.com/blog/) are displayed correctly (nice and sharp). There should be no ripped/grainy edges or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.. Would comment, not enough reputation points.

Images:
[image: first]

[image: second]

[image: third]

Comment: Thanks so much! Are you able to take a screenshot? That would be very helpful!

Comment: Thank you! This looks like the screenshot was taken from an iPad (I have one myself). Do you maybe have access to a MacBook? I was thinking about testing the desktop version of Safari rather than mobile/tablet.