Retina-Scaled Images Still Appear Blurry
I scaled my image double-size for a retina display. The display dimensions are 350x357 and my image is 700 x 714. When I add the image to my page, though, it still looks blurry, even when saved as a high-quality PNG. What's especially weird is if I open the image separately in the browser and scale it to 350x357, it looks more clear in the image preview than embedded on the web page. I have no idea what's going on!
Image viewed directly:

Image viewed in webpage:

Scaling info in web inspector:


Do this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502778/blurry-downscaled-images-in-the-chrome-84 or this https://medium.com/@uxshan/quickly-generate-responsive-images-that-work-in-all-browsers-and-massively-reduce-your-download-36a1ef6e4e60

@SioGabx It does! Applying transform: translateZ(0) seems to do the trick at least until Chrome gets its act together.

There was a bit of inspector fraud happening here. While the inspector told me the "rendered size" was 350x357, in reality it was 349.8 x 356.79 because it was inside a percentage-width container that wasn't quite hitting the 350px mark.
In addition this seems to be a Chrome issue as outlined here.

Poking around on StackOverflow got me to this answer which recommends applying transform: translateZ(0); to image elements to fix the blurriness. Not sure if that causes performance issues or not but I only have a couple images per page so I'll risk it.
